# Erro ao ler JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando ler um arquivo de JSON no php com o seguinte formato:

```js
{"leads":
  [{"id":"1",
    "email":"email@email.com",
    "user": "email@example.com",
    "first_conversion": {
      "content": {
        "identificador":"ebook-abc",
      },
      "created_at":"2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
      "conversion_origin": {
            "source": "source 1",
          }
    },
    "last_conversion": {
      "content": {
        "identificador":"webinar-abc",
        "email_lead":"suporte@rr.com.br"
      },
      "created_at":"2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
      "cumulative_sum":"2",
    },
    "custom_fields": {
        "Destino": "EUA"
      },
    "website": "http://www.site.com.br",
    "mobile_phone":"48 30252598",
    "city":"Sao Paulo",
    "state": "SP",
    "tags": ["tag 1", "tag 2"],
  }]
}
```

Tentei retornar os resultados no php em 2 formatos.
O primeiro da seguinte forma:

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($request, true);
$id = $input['leads']['nome'];
echo $id;
```

E a segunda forma utilizando foreach:

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($request, true);
$lead = $input->leads;
foreach($lead as $result){
   echo "ID: ". $result->id;
}
```

Nenhum dos dois jeitos está retornando um resultado. Alguém pode me ajudar e dizer aonde estou errando?! Obrigado :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem alguns erros em seu `json` o que fazem com que o `PHP` retorne `null` quando você utilizar o `json_decode`, os erros são as virgulas nos ultimos elementos de cada `objeto`, por exemplo:

```
"conversion_origin": {
    "source": "source 1",
}


"last_conversion": {
    "content": {
        "identificador": "webinar-abc",
        "email_lead": "suporte@rr.com.br"
    },
    "created_at": "2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
    "cumulative_sum": "2", // <-- virgula ao final
},
```

Para verificar se o `json` é valido, você pode utilizar o  [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/).

> **O último elemento de uma lista não pode conter vírgula no json**

Além disso, veja também que o indice `leads` é um `array`, desta maneira você precisara informar o numero do indice para acessa-lo como array e como objeto, veja:

```
// Utilizando array
$json = json_decode($raw, true);
var_dump($json['leads'][0]['id']); // Saida: string(1) "1"

// Utilizando objeto
$obj = json_decode($raw);
var_dump($obj->leads[0]->id); // Saida: string(1) "1"
```

#### Utilizando uma iteração

```
foreach($obj->leads as $lead) {
   echo $lead->id;
}
```

OU:

```
foreach($json['leads'] as $lead) {
    echo $lead['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Baixei seu código e testei aqui, pelo menos o erro que eu identifiquei era que seguindo o formato do seu json está dando erro na vírgula nos últimos itens da sua lista.

Ex: (errado)

```
$json = '{
      "id":[{
          "nome":"nome de teste",
          "sobrenome": "sobrenome aqui", //no caso do json a última virgula no último item não deve existir
      }]
}';
```

Ex: (correto)

```
$json = '{
      "id":[{
          "nome":"nome de teste",
          "sobrenome": "sobrenome aqui" //vírgula removida
      }]
}';
```

Testei seu formato com essas modificações que citei acima.

```
$json = '{
    "leads":[{"id":"1",
    "email":"email@email.com",
    "user": "email@example.com",
    "first_conversion": {
      "content": {
        "identificador":"ebook-abc"
      },
      "created_at":"2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
      "conversion_origin": {
            "source": "source 1"
          }
    },
    "last_conversion": {
      "content": {
        "identificador":"webinar-abc",
        "email_lead":"suporte@rr.com.br"
      },
      "created_at":"2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
      "cumulative_sum":"2"
    },
    "custom_fields": {
        "Destino": "EUA"
      },
    "website": "http://www.site.com.br",
    "mobile_phone":"48 30252598",
    "city":"Sao Paulo",
    "state": "SP",
    "tags": ["tag 1", "tag 2"]
  }]
}';

$converte = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($converte);
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu código está correto. O erro é no conteúdo do json.

O último elemento de uma lista não pode conter vírgula no json como ocorre no PHP. Se utilizar o bloco abaixo, verá que seu primeiro código funciona perfeitamente.

```
{"leads": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "user": "email@example.com",
        "first_conversion": {
            "content": {
                "identificador": "ebook-abc"
            },
            "created_at": "2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
            "conversion_origin": {
                "source": "source 1"
            }
        },
        "last_conversion": {
            "content": {
                "identificador": "webinar-abc",
                "email_lead": "suporte@rr.com.br"
            },
            "created_at": "2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
            "cumulative_sum": "2"
        },
        "custom_fields": {
            "Destino": "EUA"
        },
        "website": "http://www.site.com.br",
        "mobile_phone": "48 30252598",
        "city": "Sao Paulo",
        "state": "SP",
        "tags": [
            "tag 1",
            "tag 2"
        ]
    }
]}
```